# Initialization of array error in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, array-initialization

When I initialize an array `sbox`, I am getting syntax errors.  Please help me out.

```
  reg  [7:0] sbox[15:0];
sbox = '{
 8'h63, 8'h7c, 8'h77, 8'h7b,
 8'hf2, 8'h6b, 8'h6f, 8'hc5,
 8'h30, 8'h01, 8'h67, 8'h2b,
 8'hfe, 8'hd7, 8'hab, 8'h76
};
```

This is actually sbox.  Error it was showing:

> near "=": syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting IDENTIFIER or
>   TYPE_IDENTIFIER

I was using modelsim simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you are using for the array assignment is only valid in `SystemVerilog`, not `Verilog`.

So your compiler needs to support this, and you need to tell the compiler that the file is SystemVerilog.  Most compilers (including modelsim) will assume the file type based on the extension, e.g. `.v == Verilog` and `.sv == SystemVerilog`, while others required a switch.

In addition, as pointed out in the answer from toolic, you need to place the assignment in an `initial` block, or you could combine the declaration with the assignment, like this:

```
reg [7:0] sbox[15:0] = '{
        8'h63, 8'h7c, 8'h77, 8'h7b,
        8'hf2, 8'h6b, 8'h6f, 8'hc5,
        8'h30, 8'h01, 8'h67, 8'h2b,
        8'hfe, 8'hd7, 8'hab, 8'h76
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment should be inside an `initial` or `always` block:

```
module tb;

reg [7:0] sbox[15:0];

initial begin
    sbox = '{
        8'h63, 8'h7c, 8'h77, 8'h7b,
        8'hf2, 8'h6b, 8'h6f, 8'hc5,
        8'h30, 8'h01, 8'h67, 8'h2b,
        8'hfe, 8'hd7, 8'hab, 8'h76
    };
end

endmodule
```